# EF 4.x and Transactions

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4, transactions

Any thoughts on the following error:

```
System.Data.EntityException: An error occurred while starting a transaction on the provider connection. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.ObjectDisposedException: Safe handle has been closed
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.DangerousAddRef(Boolean& success)
   at SNINativeMethodWrapper.SNIPacketReset(SafeHandle pConn, IOType ioType, SafeHandle packet)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.WriteSni()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsExecuteTransactionManagerRequest(Byte[] buffer, TransactionManagerRequestType request, String transactionName, TransactionManagerIsolationLevel isoLevel, Int32 timeout, SqlInternalTransaction transaction, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ExecuteTransactionYukon(TransactionRequest transactionRequest, String transactionName, IsolationLevel iso, SqlInternalTransaction internalTransaction, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.BeginSqlTransaction(IsolationLevel iso, String transactionName)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel iso)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.BeginDbTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.BeginDbTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.BeginDbTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.BeginTransaction()
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptChangesDuringSave)
```

To give you a little background, we were using pure ADO.NET(no transactions) in this part of the application and it was running fine. After we switched to EF, started getting this error. I don't believe this is EF related as it is happening deep in ADO.NET transaction code. Is there any way to disable transactions in EF?

Comment: You should go back to using pure ADO.NET and IUDs. :)

Comment: Haha, thanks, Jay. That's very encouraging.

Comment: If anyone is interested, there is no way to disable transactions in EF. If you don't specify one, it will create a default one for you during SaveChanges call.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research and looking at the disassembled code, I found out that you can't disable transactions in EF.